# Why is my "clip adjustment layer to layer below" button greyed out?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to set an adjustment layer to clip to an entire group of layers, but the button is greyed out.

[image]

How can I do this? Why is the option greyed out?

(Photoshop CS5)

Answer (score 1):

I do not have your version but...Try this:

Hold the Alt key and click between the Layers: Adjustment and Group 1.

This will create a clip.

[image]